# Establishing connection to SQL Server Error

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I opened my web project today and for some reason I could not gain access to my database files. I get the following `exception` whenever I try to add, edit or refresh my database:

> A network related instance specific error occurred while establishing
>   a connection to SQL Server. The Server was not found or is was not
>   accessible.  Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL
>   Server is configured to allow remote connections.

I took a look at my connection string for any spelling errors and deleted my database and replaced it in the folder I had it in. I can't seem to find a fix for this so any help would be a appreciated. I am using Visual studio 2008 for this web project.

Comment: Did you try to authenticate to the database using Management Studio using the values from the connection string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like the same problem that I had myself awhile back.  My problem was that my SQL service pack 1 did not install properly so I had to install Microsoft SQL Server System CLR Types, Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Management Objects and Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Native Client.  After that I could create new SQLdatasources but I could not edit the ones I had previously before my problem.  I had to restart my computer in safe mode and delete my SQLEXPRESS folder then recreate the database connection in visual studios. When I finished that everything worked fine.

This is the site I got those downloads, http://blogs.cametoofar.com/post/cannot-load-file-or-assembly-microsoftsqlservermanagementsdksfc.aspx